# Angular 2 RC4 to RC5 migration difficulties

Tags: angularjs, angular

So we are trying to migrate our application from Angular 2 RC4 to RC5. Current router is 3.0.0-beta.2.

We have 5 feature components and 100 odd shared components. When the change is made to RC5, and app.module is added and main.ts is updated, will the application still run? It has been said that for now the directives and pipes will be automatically hoisted.

Also, will RC5 work with the router still at 3.0.0-beta.2?

Comment: Why not upgrade to the final version right away? The hard part for you in the introduction of ngModule in RC5. After that there wasn't big changes

Comment: Why don't you use the 2.0 final release?

Comment: We're in the process of migrating from RC4 to final. Its a pain. Considering going the RC5 route as well. RC5 preserves backward compatibility. The final release does not. Once on RC5, the transition to final should be easier. Everything should work according to this article: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/rc4-to-rc5.html